# Cloud9 "local" and "cloud" code completion differs.

Tags: cloud9-ide

When I use online version of Cloud9 at c9.io I can see "smart and sexy" contextual completion for Node.js api and other javascript with documentation.
But if I install cloud9 locally from github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9 I have only plain suggestion of used words.

Is smart completion a feature of proprietary online version or something is wrong with my local installation?